# How to include custom fonts in iOS7?

Tags: iphone, ios7

I've included like always font file into project but it's not working in application. Is there some new way in iOS7 to include custom font?

This is my code which I used for iOS6:

Category:

```
+ (id)e_FontOpenSansBold:(CGFloat)size
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:size];
}
```

in app:

```
descriptionTextView.font = [UIFont e_FontOpenSansBold:30.0];
```

There is no error, just text is not in open sans bold like it was i previous iOS.

Comment: Can you confirm that this works in previous versions?

Comment: @danielhanly.com - This works in previous versions. I literally copy/paste from old project.

Comment: Did you also add the relevant plist entries for the custom font: The key you need to add is called ‘Fonts provided by application‘, or ‘UIAppFonts‘ if you’re viewing via Source Code.

Comment: Does it actually work when you run this specific project on iOS 6?

Comment: @FilipRadelic - Yap. This has something do with that that I opened in Xcode 5 and than again in Xcode 4.6. I found solution: delete label and create new again and it works. Weird.